# AngularJS - Controller can't be found

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-bootstrap

So I've tried to make a script which would load the files needed for my `AngularJS` application.

But when I run the `Angular.bootstrap` part I get this error

[Error description at AngularJS home page](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ng/areq?p0=masterController&p1=not%20a%20function,%20got%20undefined)

This error is due to `AngularJS` not being able to find my `masterController` why is this. I've checked that the name of the module match, as well as the name of the controller and they do. So I'm very confused as to why I won't recognize the controller.

My code looks like this:

**Index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-controller="masterController">
<head>
    <!-- META -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"><!-- Optimize mobile viewport -->
    <meta name="author" content="Michael Tot Korsgaard">

    <title>Mythodea map explorer</title>

    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png">

    <script src="lib/JQuery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="lib/AngularJS/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/AngularJS/1.5.5/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/AngularJS/1.5.5/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/UI-Router/0.2.18/ui-router.min.js"></script>

    <script src="lib/moment/2.13.0/moment.js"></script>

    <script src="js/log.js"></script>
    <script src="js/build.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-cloak>
    <div ui-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**core.js**

```
var app = angular.module('AcademiaUnitate', [
        'ui.router',
        'ngAnimate'
      ]);
```

**master.controller.js**

```
angular.module('AcademiaUnitate')
.controller('masterController', function ($scope) {
});
```

**build.js** where my angular files are being added to my `<head>` tag

```
var buildStart = moment(),
    fileCounter = 0;
initialize();
function initialize(){
    loadJson('app')
        .done(function(response){
            var files = response.files,
                folders = response.folders;
            getFiles(files, 'app')
                .done(function(response){
                    getFolders(folders, 'app')
                        .done(function(response){
                            bootstrap();
                        });
                })
       });
}

function getFolders(folders, path){
    var deferred = $.Deferred();

    if(folders.length > 0){
       loadFolder(path + '/' + folders[0])
            .done(function(response){
                folders.splice(0, 1);
                getFolders(folders, path)
                    .done(function(response){
                        deferred.resolve(response);
                    });
            });
   } else {
        deferred.resolve(true);
    }

    return deferred.promise();
}

function getFiles(files, path){
    var deferred = $.Deferred();

    if(files.length > 0){
        loadFile(path + '/' + files[0])
            .done(function(response){
                files.splice(0, 1);
                getFiles(files, path)
                   .done(function(response){
                        deferred.resolve(response);
                    });
            });
    } else {
        deferred.resolve(true);
    }

    return deferred.promise();
}
function loadFile(src){
    var defer = $.Deferred(),
        fileType = src.substring(src.lastIndexOf(".") + 1, src.length);

    var head = $('head');

    fileCounter++;

    if(fileType.toLowerCase() === 'js'){
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        script.src = src;
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
        defer.resolve(true);
    } else {
        defer.resolve(true);
    }

    return defer.promise();
}
function loadFolder(path){
    var defer = $.Deferred();

    loadJson(path)
        .done(function(response){
            var folders = response.folders,
                files = response.files;

            if(folders !== undefined){
                getFolders(folders, path)
                    .done(function(response){
                        if(files !== undefined){
                            getFiles(files, path)
                                .done(function(response){
                                    defer.resolve(response);
                                });
                        } else {
                            defer.resolve(response);
                        }
                    });
            } else {
                if(files !== undefined){
                    getFiles(files, path)
                        .done(function(response){
                            defer.resolve(response);
                        });
                } else {
                    defer.resolve(response);
                }
            }
        });

    return defer.promise();
}

function loadJson(path){
    var defer = $.Deferred();
    $.get(path + '/structure.json', function(response) {
        defer.resolve(response);
    });
    return defer.promise();
}

function bootstrap(){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var bootstrapStart = moment();
        angular.bootstrap(function(){
        });
    });
}
```

What my build.js file does is to find the file `structure.json` which tells which `js` files to add to the `<head>` tag and then which folders to look for additional `structure.json` files. When all that is done angular will be bootstrapped.

Comment: Try removing `angular.module('AcademiaUnitate').controller` and adding `app.controller`.

Comment: The reason for it being like that is due to the two being in seperate files 

Comment: No problem with that. You can write like that.

Comment: you mention a file `core.js` that isn't listed in this HTML, and a `controller` that it's not clear if that's a file or just a definition somewhere.  Also, you aren't supplying a module to your `bootstrap()` function.

Comment: you are missing ng-app in html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, it was the way I bootstrapped my application had to change

```
angular.bootstrap(function(){});
```

into

```
angular.bootstrap(document, ['AcademiaUnitate']);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should probably consider naming your controller properly

```
angular.module('AcademiaUnitate')
  .controller('MasterController', function MasterController($scope) {

});
```

Please see the controller documentation for the latest angular1 version at https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller and an example at https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_02

If all your angular code is in one file, you may want to do the following:
1) chain the controller after/ to the angular.module()

```
angular.module('AcademiaUnitate', [
    'ui.router',
    'ngAnimate'
]).controller('MasterController', function MasterController($scope) {

});
```

OR 2)use the app variable

```
var app = angular.module('AcademiaUnitate', [
    'ui.router',
    'ngAnimate'
]);

app.controller('MasterController', function MasterController($scope) {

});
```

Comment: Having a named or anonymous function didn't fix it, but you're right it would be better practice to use named functions.  I've updated my question to clarify my problem ;-) +1 for good practice advise :-)

Answer (score 1):

The file containing the masterController function is missing when Angular is bootstraping the application. Include the file. Help this help

Comment: That is because I'm adding it via the `build.js` script. I've updated my question to clarify my problem ;-) +1

Answer (score 1):

You haven't included core.js in your index.html. That is why your controller is not found. Try including it.

```
<script src="core.js"></script>
```

Comment: That is because I'm adding it via the `build.js` script. I've updated my question to clarify my problem ;-) +1

Comment: I wasn't aware about the updated question. But still thanks, hope it will help someone else : )

Answer (score 1):

you probably forget to add `ng-app="AcademiaUnitate"`, just change `<html ng-controller="masterController">` to `<html ng-app="AcademiaUnitate" ng-controller="masterController">`

Comment: If I add `ng-app` to my `<html>` tag it will start bootstrapping the application before I've added the `js` scripts needed. I've updated my question to clarify my problem ;-) +1 for spotting `ng-app` was missing